# Why For Loop Step -0.1 get wrong data

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I have a series of for loops with negative start and end values with steps at -0.1 and I had some oddities in the calculations.

I set out to create this very simple for loop to see what the system was doing, and this is the output:

**Original Script**:

```
For number As Double = 2 To 0 Step -0.1
    Debug.Write(number.ToString & " ")
Next
```

**Output**:

> 2 1,9 1,8 1,7 1,6 1,5 1,4 1,3 1,2 1,1 0,999999999999999
> 0,899999999999999 0,799999999999999 0,699999999999999
> 0,599999999999999 0,499999999999999 0,399999999999999
> 0,299999999999999 0,199999999999999 0,0999999999999994

**Right Output** Updated on 02/dec/2023

> 2 1,9 1,8 1,7 1,6 1,5 1,4 1,3 1,2 1,1 1,0 0,9 0,8 0,7 0,6 0,5 0,4 0,3 0,2 0,1 0,0

As you can see it doesn't get to 0
The problem does this with any number of puts as end, it doesn't get to calculate it.

What could the problem be due to?

Comment: Floating point number (ex. Double) are not very precise for this kind of operations (see the link I posted above) You could maybe use `Decimal` or only use Integers in you loop and use some math to display the right thing

Comment: I don't understand why you think it should go to 0 immediately after 1.1.

Comment: Alternative duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken